# How to only return 1 row when meet either subquery condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I work with electronic health records and need to determine % of patients who meet specific criteria. Note: Because the data is from EHR software, I don't have any control over how the tables and fields are organized.

My denominator is all patients who meet certain criteria, say PatientDenominator (for example: all patients who had XYZ123 service and were seen in July 2016 in a particular state). My numerator is how many in PatientDenominator had checkbox1 OR checkbox2 checked in the past year.

Except that these checkboxes are not evaluated at every visit - only at certain visits. So I have these as subqueries but because I put them in the FROM statement, when a patient meets both criteria they get two rows returned, which skews the numerator (which I'm doing in Excel for now since I'm still trying to figure out the query).

How do I reorganize the query so I can get only 1 row - when the patient meets EITHER criteria?  The only way I see how is doing a CASE (when Scenario1 = 1 then 1 when Scenario2 = 1 then 1, else 0) but is that the best way to do it? I'm new to this sort of complexity and since I'll be evaluating many months at a time (and about 5,000 patients a month) I worry a little about performance.

```
declare
  @startdate DATE,
  @enddate DATE

set  @startdate = '2016-07-01' 
set  @enddate = '2016-08-01'

select
  PatientNumber,
  PatientSex,
  case
    when (Scenario1='1' OR Scenario2='1') then 'Meets Criteria'
    when (checkbox1 is null and checkbox2 is null) then 'N/A'
    else 'Not Meet Criteria'
  end 'Criteria'
from
  PatientTable PT
  left join VisitTable VT on PT.person_id=VT.person_id
  left join LocationTable lt on VT.location_id=lt.location_id
  left join TableZ on VT.VisitID=TableZ.VisitID
  left join (
    select distinct
        PT1.person_id,
        case
          when TableA.checkbox1 = '1' OR TableB.checkbox2 = '1')
            then '1'
            else '0'
        end Scenario1Eval
    from 
        PatientTable1 PT1
        left join VisitTable1 VT1 on PT1.person_id=VT1.person_id
        left join TableA on VT1.VisitID=TableA.VisitID
        left join TableB on VT1.VisitID=TableB.VisitID
        left join TableC on VT1.VisitID=TableC.VisitID
    where
        sex='f'
        and TableC.VisitType in ('Type1','Type2')
        and (VT1.VisitDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@startdate) and VT1.VisitDate  < @enddate )
    ) as Scenario1 on PT.person_id=Scenario1.person_id
  left join (
    select distinct
        PT2.person_id,
        case
            when TableA2.checkbox1 = '1' OR TableB2.checkbox2 = '1')
            then '1'
            else '0'
        end Scenario2Eval
    from 
        PatientTable1 PT2
        left join VisitTable1 VT2 on PT2.person_id=VT2.person_id
        left join TableA2 on VT2.VisitID=TableA2.VisitID
        left join TableB2 on VT2.VisitID=TableB2.VisitID
        left join TableD2 on VT2.VisitID=TableD2.VisitID
    where
        (VT1.VisitDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@startdate) and VT1.VisitDate <    @enddate )
    and (TableD2.ChargeCode like '9920%' OR TableD2.ChargeCode like '9938%')) as Scenario2 on PT.person_id=Scenario2.person_id
  where
    VT1.VisitDate > @startdate and VT1.VisitDate < @enddate
    and TableZ.QualifyingField = 'Y'
    and lt.state='ZZ'
    and (Scenario1 is not null OR Scenario2 is not null)
```

Comment: You need to decide on how you aggregate a number of rows in subquery to what you named ' a patient meets criteria'. Probably `min(case
                when TableA.checkbox1 = '1' OR TableB.checkbox2 = '1')
                then '1'
                else '0'
            end)` if all rows must have `1`. Or max() if just one `1` will suffice.

Comment: can you use a MRN instead of a VisitID?

Comment: I agree with Serg. There seem to be three or four possible states per checkbox: 0, 1, NULL, no record. And there probably can be several visits per person in the time given. So there can be many combinations ( e.g. 1 x checkbox1 = 0, 1 x checkbox2 = 0, 1 x checkbox2 = NULL). So what to do in what situation? BTW: Do you actually know what a left join does (in contrast to an inner join)?

Comment: There are only a few places I could use an inner join because I need to know when something is not "a match". So really only patient, visit, and location tables can use an inner. The other visit tables I use are populated depending on what EHR template was used (which depends on what kind of visit a patient had and the workflow the health center uses).

Comment: Can I use MRN on the joins? I guess I'm not sure because I need to control the date range of the visits (I can't use a visit prior to a year before the start/end dates), and I don't know how to do that other than to link via VisitID. I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: I used the max and that works well - thank you! (and yes there are many combinations, but if I get a 1 then it counts as a 1 regardless of any other value. But I also need to know the 0 for the denominator. Now I just need to test the data and see if I get any NULLs because those are the ones that'll muck things up. I don't think it is possible but I won't know until I check. welcome to the world of Clinical Quality Measures.)

Comment: The other next step is figuring out how to sum my 1/0.

Comment: and done. Thanks so much for you help!